# What's the name of Visual Studio Import UI Widget (picture inside)

Tags: visual-studio

What's the name of the circled UI element here?  And how do I access it using keyboard shortcuts?  Sometimes it's nearly impossible to get the mouse to focus on it.

```
catch (ItemNotFoundException e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know the name, but the shortcuts are CTRL-period (.) and ALT-SHIFT-F10.  Handy to know :)

Answer (score 4):

It's called a SmartTag